# Convert the string data into an array

Tags: .net

Below i'm storing sensitive data in string but i want to keep it array to make it more secure how can I convert that.

```
 stringName = $"Server={secretProps.host};Port={secretProps.port};database={_db};User Id={secretProps.username};Password={secretProps.password};convert zero datetime=True";
```

Comment: "i want to keep it array to make it more secure" - please could you explain what you mean by this? Where are you "keeping" it, and in what way is an array more secure?

Comment: It looks like a connection string, but for what kind of server/database? I guess you can always create a new SqlConnection (if SQL server/database) and you can always get the connection string property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look into Microsoft docs about the SecureString class.
*https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-6.0*

For the question:

1. You can make an array that has strings like this:

```
string[] arr = { "One", "Two", "Three" };
```

2. You can make a List, and add a "string" to that List and convert to an array later with .ToArray()

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add(yourStringVariable);
var array = list.ToArray();
```

3. You can split a string with string.Split(), which returns an array of strings.

```
string myString = ("apple,something else,etc");
var myArray = myString.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

as above, if you want to split the string into array you can use the string.split() function for secure strings see

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-6.0